# content inside table do not generate TOC

Tags: ms-word

When building TOC if a content heading is inside a table it does not show in the navigation pane.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByIVY.png

Comment: There is a difference between the Navigation Pane and the Table of Contents. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd

Comment: Hello Malik, I would suggest you close your own question and post elsewhere. This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow which is a forum about programming, not about using applications. You question would be better posted on Super User (https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word) or Microsoft Answers (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1473637240674).

Comment: To my knowledge, the Navigation Pane has never captured Heading level styles that are in a table. That holds true for both the Windows and Mac versions of the product. They do however, display in a document's printable Table of Contents. As it has been said, since your question is not about programming code solutions you should ask it elsewhere if you want to pursue the discussion further.